# React: Element type is invalid when using react-weather

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am getting confused. Having a self written component, using [react-weather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-weather) installed via `npm` as the following:

My `Weather.js` components in (`src/components` folder)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GenericWeather } from 'react-weather';

class Weather extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GenericWeather city="Tampere" temp="17.61" status="sun" />
    );
  }
}

export default Weather;
```

The `App.js` is located in the `src/` folder, and look as the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Weather from './components/Weather';


    class App extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Weather />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Causes the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'Weather'.

I was wondering, since the `export` and `import` looked okay for me, tried changing the `GenericWeather`, to simply:

```
<div>
   <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

And voila, the error is gone.

So, at this point, i am curious, how can I get the `react-weather` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the latest version of react-weather, if you import it you find that the only 2 named exports available are: `YahooWeather` and `AccuWeather`.

<s>It seems documentation is outdated.</s>

Edit:
I cloned the repo and created a new build, that indeed works as the documentation states.
If you want to use it you need to do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/AmarShaked/ReactWeather
yarn install (inside root folder of the cloned repo)
yarn build (to fire the webpack new build)
```

Thus inside `[repo_root]/lib/index.js` you will have the uglified package. You can copy to the project you are using and then reference in your code like this.

```
import { GenericWeather } from '../[relative_path_to_script]/index';
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me where did you find the repository for it?

Comment: Here you have: https://github.com/AmarShaked/ReactWeather. I am taking a look to see if I can fix it and make a PR because it seems a broken build. Source code is according to documentation, but webpack build is not.

Comment: But here ( https://github.com/AmarShaked/ReactWeather/tree/master/src ) the 2 components are there named with `GenericWeather` and `OpenWeatherMap`. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Working! Thanks for figuring this out!